# How can I return a boolean value from this toggle button listener?

Tags: android, return-value, android-togglebutton

I need to return a boolean value from the toggle button listener to switch the system on and off. With the method being void, it yells at me if I try to return a boolean. If boolean is not possible, returning a string would suffice. I am new to android so the answer is probably simple but I am lost. Thanks in advance!

The imports

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);


    //creating database instance
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    final DatabaseReference rootRef = database.getReference("user/key/plants/reaper");
    //FirebaseDatabase data = new FirebaseDatabase("test-5487a/user/key/plants/reaper");
    //mRef = new FirebaseDatabase("https://test-5487a.firebaseio.com/");
```

The toggle button and listener

```
    ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.PowerButton);
    toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                // The toggle is enabled
            } else {
                // The toggle is disabled
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call a function within the callback to update the state of your system.

```
ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.PowerButton);
toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        setSystem(isChecked);
    }
});
```

And then implement your actual system.

```
public void setSystem(boolean isChecked) {
    if(isChecked) {
        // Turn the system on.
    } else {
        // Turn the system off.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The toggle button listener is actually a `void` function. What that means is that you cannot return any parameter. You can only execute things.
So instead of returning a boolean, here is a few thing you can do:

You can switch the system on or off in the listener.
For example:

```
ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.PowerButton);
toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            // The toggle is enabled
            // --> Switch system on
        } else {
            // The toggle is disabled
            // --> Switch system off
        }
    }
});
```

Or what you can do is create a function that takes for parameter a boolean such as `switchSystem(boolean on)` and then call it in the listener, just like this:

```
ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.PowerButton);
toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        switchSystem(isChecked);
    }
});

...

void switchSystem(boolean on) {
    if (on) {
        // --> Switch system on
    }else{
        // --> Switch system off
    }
}
```